# How to keep track of objects generated in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have a form that dynamically generates different inputs, it does this by appending objects to an array.

```
$scope.data = {
    urls: [{}],
    features: [{}],
    testemonies: [{}],
    keywords: [{}],
    tests: [{}],
    newsletters: [{}],
    devFields: [{}],
    devSteps: [{
        id: $scope.devStepsAmount
    }],
    loginFields: [{}],
    steps: [{
        fields: [{}]
    }]
};

$scope.addDevStep = function() {
    $scope.data.devSteps.push({
        id: ++($scope.devStepsAmount)
    });
    console.log($scope.data.devSteps);
};
```

Then on the HTML i simply call them using an ng-repeat

`<div class="card-body single" ng-repeat="devStep in data.devSteps">`

And i call the function that adds a new object in HTML like this

`<button class="btn btn-simple" data-ng-click="addDevStep()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New Step</button>`

Now my problem is that i need to be able to keep track of each individual object generated and store it's ID on the moment of creation, how do you do this in Javascript/Angular?

Sorry for the silly question, i'm more of a PHP person

Comment: why not creating a global counter? then use devSteps.push(id, yourValue)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var devStepsAmount = 0;
$scope.data = {
    urls: [{}],
    features: [{}],
    testemonies: [{}],
    keywords: [{}],
    tests: [{}],
    newsletters: [{}],
    devFields: [{}],
    devSteps: [{
    }],
    loginFields: [{}],
    steps: [{
        fields: [{}]
    }]
};

$scope.addDevStep = function() {
    devStepsAmount++;
    $scope.data.devSteps['id'] = devStepsAmount;
    console.log($scope.data.devSteps);
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that works just fine, i wanted to avoid that though cause i'm gonna have to repeat it for the other arrays however :( 
If there's no other way then i guess i have to do it like that, thank you for your help :)